# How to manage audience Manager Database Address Books

Tags: outbound-email, audience-manager

How we should manage Audience Manager Database Address Books. If I have multiple brand site and each brand has multiple countries site. I want one contact can subscribe in each brand.
So how could I manage contacts among these sites. Please give me an expert suggestion. It will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little tricky to answer with absolute certainty here, since it depends on a lot of variables. In the end, it's up to you to decide what works for you -- perhaps with the input of some expert consultants that can help you consider all of the variables.

From what limited information you have given, it sounds like you only need a single static Address Book. You could then control the brands that they are a part of using Keywords and filter the Contacts in each brand by the relevant Keyword (if that's what you want), using Dynamic Address Books or Dynamic Distribution Lists.

Again, there's lots of options to consider before deciding on a final design. Should your users always have access to all of the Contacts? Or only the ones for their brand? Does a Contact (profile) need to be the same across all brands or does signing up for brand A and brand B involve two different accounts? etc.

Comment: Peter, My user will always have access common contacts of brand and location access not complete brand contacts. Like we have 3 brands brand A,brand B,brand C and 10 locations location A, location B,.... Like brand A have 100 contacts but brand A and location A have 10 common contacts.Then my location A user can see only 10 contacts not full brand contacts. And user also have the ability to import contacts from .csv file only for his location. All brands have different sign up.

Comment: This isn't really the best place for those kinds of discussions, but it sounds like you need an Address Book for each brand at least (since they need to have separate accounts for the same Contact). You could then create Dynamic Address Books for the brand+location combination so that your users can only see the overlap -- but I don't think there is any way you can limit the import to only the overlap. I think they'll be able to import any Contacts into the brand Address Book as a whole. So that would need to be handled by your own business rules.